# Uploading binary file using axios?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I am trying to upload a zip file from my server-side application (Express.js) to a third-party API as a binary (not a `multipart/form-data` but as the equivalent of body binary in Postman), but I get the following error from `axios`:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Name/[object Object]']
```

My current situation:

```
form = new FormData();
form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/' + req.files), req.files.name);
axios.post(url, form, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}`
    }
});
```

`req.files` output:

```
file: {
    name: 'myfile.zip',
    data: <Buffer 50 4b 03 04 0a 00 00 00 00 00 66 6c 75 52 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1f 00 09 00 64 6f 63 6b 65 72 2d 6d 69 6e 65 63 72 61 66 74 2d 73 65 72 ... 139643 more bytes>,
    size: 139693,
    encoding: '7bit',
    tempFilePath: '',
    truncated: false,
    mimetype: 'application/zip',
    md5: 'e2b648ad295922c6d8d3ef1bc8ce1309',
    mv: [Function: mv]
}
```

Comment: `console.log(req.files)`

Comment: @madflow `file: {
    name: 'myfile.zip',
    data: <Buffer 50 4b 03 04 0a 00 00 00 00 00 66 6c 75 52 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1f 00 09 00 64 6f 63 6b 65 72 2d 6d 69 6e 65 63 72 61 66 74 2d 73 65 72 ... 139643 more bytes>,
    size: 139693,
    encoding: '7bit',
    tempFilePath: '',
    truncated: false,
    mimetype: 'application/zip',
    md5: 'e2b648ad295922c6d8d3ef1bc8ce1309',
    mv: [Function: mv]
  }
}
`

Comment: I had a similar problem. Maybe you can fix it with this:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58996278/how-to-send-binary-stream-from-string-content-to-third-party-api-using-axios-nod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58996278/how-to-send-binary-stream-from-string-content-to-third-party-api-using-axios-nod)

Answer (score 0):

req.files is an object, so the path given to fs.createReadStream can't be correct.

More over, req.files contains 1 or multiple other objects representing file(s) uploaded to your server application. So you first need to get the file object you want in req.files (file in your case) --> req.files.file

So to give correct path to to your zip file in fs.createReadStream, you should use req.files.file.name. Same rule for the name given (3rd argument) in form.append.

However I doubt __dirname + '/' + req.files.file.name is the correct path to the file you're trying to upload (I don't think you saved it?). So you should try the data buffer from your file object instead.
For example:

```
const { data, name } = req.files.file;
form.append('file', data, name);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However, it seems the 3rd party API expects to receive a binary zip file through the `req.body` not through `multipart/form-data`. Hence my file isn't recognized as valid by the server. This is where my issue is. How to reproduce a file binary upload via the body just like I usually do with postman ?

Comment: @Johndoe Did you try: `axios( { method: "post", url: url, data: req.files.file.data, headers: { "Content-Type": "application/zip" }  } )`?

Comment: Yes. I did try it. Doesn't work

Comment: @Johndoe And what is the error returned by the API ?