# How to send binary data of a file in a request body?

Tags: node.js, axios

Is there any way to send binary data of a file in body of a put request using nodejs and axios ?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58996278/how-to-send-binary-stream-from-string-content-to-third-party-api-using-axios-nod) help?

Comment: Does buffer.from outputs data in binary format?

Comment: check [this](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfromarray).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a FormData append your file to it , send it with axios then get it with multer in server side.

```
const data = new FormData()
data.append('multer_file_name', file, file.name)
axios.post("your_api", data, {
    headers: {
        accept: 'application/json',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Content-Type': undefined,
         },
}).then((response) => {
})
```

you can get your file like this if you have an input :

```
const file = document.getElementById('your_input_id').files[0]
```

Comment: this code is invalid for binary file types and node environment.